# LinQ Substring Function From the Right

Tags: linq-to-sql

Im new to linQ and I've got a problem

Question: if i have a string Example "MySTring"and I need the characters at positions 5 and 6 counting from the right of the string, ie: "ST"

here's my Query

Dim result = From everyval in AllVals
             where everyval.Substring(5,2)='ST'
             select everyval.Name

Now this wont return the correct values from the database because the default Consideration of positions in the Substring Function is from LEft to Right.
One Solution is maybe to reverse the String and then apply the Substring Function to it.
But how should i be doing this?

can someone tell me..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather strange requirement, usually an `IndexOf/Contains` is good enough for this. However, you could try (conceptually) truncating the value and testing the end using `EndsWith`.

Something like this perhaps (untested and probably doesn't work):

```
Dim result = from everyval in AllVals where everyval.Remove(4).EndsWidth("ST")
```

MSDN nicely lists the string functions that can be safely translated to SQL from LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688085

Comment: Thank you Tom, EndsWith did the job